# Python sending messages to discord

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, discord, python-asyncio

I have the following issue.
I have multi threaded application and i want it to send a message to discord channel when specific condition is met.
The discord module: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is created to follow async/await notation. My application is multithreaded because it is more CPU bound than IO.
I want to combine my multi threaded app with async/await discord module.
I have created the following piece of code.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

class DiscordConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = "token"
        self.imageFolder = "folder"
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.create_task(self.client.start(self.token))

        self.thread = Thread(target=self.loop.run_forever)
        self.thread.start()


        self.channels = {
            "chanel1":channel1_id,
            "channel2":channel2_id,
            "channel3":channel3_id,
        }

     def sendMessage(self, symbol, imageFilename):
        symbols = symbol.split("_")
        symbol = symbols[0].lower()
        interval = symbols[1]
        self.client.get_channel(self.channels[symbol]).send("message", file=discord.File(file))
```

I call it in other module by creating the object of DiscordConnector and calling the sendMessage method.
The problem which I have is that self.client.get_channel(self.channels[symbol]) reuturns None object, it looks like can't get to the self.client object from sendMessage.
The initialization of the client looks ok, becuase the server is marked as online in discord application.
Do you have any ideas how to combine my multi threaded app with discord async/await syntax to call the method from DiscordConnector when there is such purpose in order to send a message to discord channel.

Comment: If you call `self.channels[symbol]` manually, does it return the correct "channel_id"?

Comment: Yes, this is a dict, which holds mapping from channel name to channel id, and self.channels[symbols] return proper id.

Comment: Ok, and using that ID manually works with `discord.Client().get_channel()`? I'm sorry if these are basic questions but I just want to cover all bases.

Comment: No it also doesn't work. In the case of my problem, I think that the issue might be related to the threading, because discord module assumes using async/await syntax but i just want to stay with the threads and somehow wrap client initialization which demands event loop and so on.